# Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<User[]>'

Tags: angular, typescript

When I change my method to call a dynamic object, I got an error.

This way, with a static data my function works:

```
this.countries = COUNTRIES
  .map((country, i) => ({id: i + 1, ...country}))
  .slice((this.page - 1) * this.pageSize, (this.page - 1) * this.pageSize + this.pageSize);
```

When I call a dynamic data from firebase:

```
users: User[];

...

this.countries = this.users
  .map((country, i) => ({id: i + 1, ...country}))
  .slice((this.page - 1) * this.pageSize, (this.page - 1) * this.pageSize + this.pageSize);
```

I got this:

> core.js:4197 ERROR NullInjectorError:
> R3InjectorError(LayoutModule)[DecimalPipe -> DecimalPipe ->
> DecimalPipe -> DecimalPipe]:    NullInjectorError: No provider for
> DecimalPipe!

and if I try to pipe it:

```
this.countries = this.users.pipe(
  map((country, i) => ({id: i + 1, ...country}))
  .slice((this.page - 1) * this.pageSize, (this.page - 1) * this.pageSize + this.pageSize)
);
```

I got:

> Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'User[]'.
> this.countries = this.users.pipe(

and I'm importing DecimalPipe on my component:

```
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';
```

and declaring it on my constructor:

```
constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore, private pipe: DecimalPipe) {
```

Comment: Stop adding the `angularjs` tag to your posts. It doesn't apply for Angular 2+ related questions.

Comment: I see a lot of mess here. Pipes need to be declared in the relative `module` and they can be used in the html. Pipes also doesn't affect the data but just their visual rappresentation.